# Killing processes with psutil

Tags: python, windows-7, windows-xp

I'm looking to write some code that will kill off a process based on it's name and who owns it. This works fine on Windows XP but when I come to run the same code on Windows 7 I get Access Denied errors when trying to get the username of the process.

Is there an easier way to kill a process that will work on XP and Win7?

The check to see if the process is owned by the 'SYSTEM' is actually needed so I can check when the process has user processes are finished, as the SYSTEM process remains, and I'm not concerned with this one.

```
PROCNAME = 'python.exe'
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
  if proc.name == PROCNAME:
    p = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
  
    if not 'SYSTEM' in p.username:
      proc.kill()
```

Comment: Killing off the SYSTEM process on XP also fails with Access Denied.

Comment: can you kill the SYSTEM process from task manager ?

Comment: Yes, and also from taskkill, but I need to be able to scan through the list of processes and find out if the process is a SYSTEM process or USER process, and I am also checking that the USER process has finished before I clean up any other instances.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the privilege to kill a process with PSUTIL, you're not going to have it with *anything else*. The first thing that comes to mind is, obviously, [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control), which appeared exactly between XP and Windows 7. Which implies that your PSUTIL must run from an elevated prompt, not surprising. Add a manifest to [request elevation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Requesting_elevation).

Comment: I do have UAC turned off on the Windows 7 machine. Will that not be enough? Ideally I would like the simplest solution possible.

Answer (score 1):

Starting october 2010 ([see issue 114](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/issues/detail?id=114)), `username` is obtained using a C function call (see `get_process_username` in the [source](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/trunk/psutil/_psutil_mswindows.c))

This means it suffers from the problem described in [this previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800924/get-process-username-c)

Basically you can catch the `AccessDenied` exception and assume the user is either 'SYSTEM' or 'LOCAL SERVICE'

**Edit:** From what I see there is also a bug in Python that causes many more AccessDenied errors than there should have been. The `SetSeDebug` function from psutil calls `RevertToSelf` at the end, practically reverting all the changes it has done.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is some of the processes does not have names, and therefor you get the error.

If you put that in a try block it will work:

```
PROCNAME = 'python.exe'
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
  try:
      if proc.name == PROCNAME:
      p = psutil.Process(proc.pid)

      etc..
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: This is not the problem. If it were, user1351549 would get an AttributeError instead of an AccessDenied exception. Also, please don't use bare `except:`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but maybe UAC is preventing Python from having administrator privileges. Try executing Python as administrator using the "run as administrator" thingy on Win 7 (I don't remember where it is exactly, but it probably involves launching a terminal as administrator, which can be done from the Start Menu, and then executing your Python script from there).

Answer (score -1):

In case psutil  does not work, you can always try using taskkill through os.system (command prompt)
Example to kill all excel instances:

```
import os
os.system("""taskkill /f /im excel.exe""")
```