# Google Chrome - Can Exit on Windows but not on Mac

Tags: python

I have successfully created a Python script to look at Twitter user tweets on both Windows 10 and on a MacBook Pro.  When I switch from user to user in the script I close Chrome using Python as follows.

```
os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
```

Then I open a new set of tabs for the tweets from the next user

This works perfectly in Windows but does not work on the Mac and no error is generated and the new user tweets are simply added as additional browser tabs. (I use webbrowser - it works fine.) To close on the Mac I just do a keyboard `option-command-w`  to close all tabs. Is there a way I can get around this programmatically?

After looking at comments the Osx equivalent to Windows taskkill (kill) did not work either.  No error was generated.  I tried psutil as described in the link but this did not work.  Also no error. [Killing processes with PSUTIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051485/killing-processes-with-psutil)

Comment: taskkill is a windows command. OSx equivalent is kill.

Comment: you might wanna check for os with https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform and then put the kill commands in the if